# Getting default credentials, like Outlook

Tags: c#, credentials, exchange-server-2003

I'm developping, in c#, an application that will (among other things) send e-mail.

The idea would be to have -- for example -- an "order this item" button, and when they click it, the system sends an e-mail to some Exchange e-mail group with the item's ID.

The deal is the following:

- users have logged into Windows with some credentials. I'd like to avoid people needing to re-type these credentials in my application
- I'd like that the person who receives the e-mail see the currently logged in user as the author of the e-mail
- We use Outlook 2003 and Exchange Server 2003.

The thing is, when we set-up outlook, we only need to type in the server address and the full name, but the system never asks for a password...

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, why do you need to use a client side program like Outlook to send the email, why not just use [System.Net.Mail](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) provided by the framework.

Comment: I didn't look at it for a reason. In pure logic, sending a mail requires accessing a mail server. In this case, the mail server will require credentials. So either i need to ask the end-user for his own credentials, or i need to create a "sender account" and use this account's credentials. The result being that all mails sent by my program will seem to come from a single person...

Comment: You can set the sender's email address and name programatically, that way even if people reply, they will reply to the address you injected in code